# How can I separate the coefficients of $x^k$ and $x^k \log x$ in a function?

Tags: coefficients

I have a function of the following form:

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + b_1 x \log x + b_2 x^2 \log x + b_3 x^3 \log x + ..., \tag{1}$$

and I would like to collect the coefficient $a_k$ and $b_k$ separately. As an example, when I do e.g. `Coefficient[f, x, 1]`, the output is:

$$a_1 + b_1 \log x, \tag{2}$$

while I would like the output to be $a_1$ only of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Coefficient` twice. First `Coefficient[f, x, 1]` to get the coefficients of `x^1` and then you can collect the coefficients of `Log[x]` to separate the two terms:

```
f = a + b x + c x Log[x];
Coefficient[Coefficient[f, x, 1], Log[x], {0, 1}]
```

> {b, c}

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!